# Get a array from MySQL to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

I have made an php code to get the array of data from MYSQL but now i am struggling to get it back to my android and just to toast it.

Here is my php code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $user_id  = $_GET['user_id'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $user_tags = array();

           foreach ($_REQUEST['user_id'] as $key => $val) {
           $user_tags[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }
            $user_ids = "'" . implode("','", $user_tags) . "'";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tags WHERE user_id IN ({$user_ids})";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//creating a blank array 
$result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    $result['tags'][] = $row['tags'];   
       }

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

here is the URL for the code:"http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Cuboid/tagsTest.php?user_id[]=7"

here is the Result for the php code:
{"result":{"tags":["Pascol","PHP","Python"]}}

i want to get this "result" toasted in my android.

here is my android code:

```
 public class Jobs extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String tags;

private String JSON_STRING;
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
public static final String KEY_USER_TAGS="tags";
public static final String URL_GET_TAG =   "http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Cuboid/tagsTest.php?user_id[]=";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jobs);


    getJSON();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tags,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

private void showEmployee() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            tags = jo.getString(KEY_USER_TAGS);

            HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(KEY_USER_TAGS, tags);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Jobs.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showEmployee();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(URL_GET_TAG);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}
```

But i get only  the blank toast . help me guys if i had made any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Hey AsyncTask does not work synchronously, if you toast like this it will work.

```
private void showEmployee() {
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
        tags = jo.getString(KEY_USER_TAGS);

        HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
        employees.put(KEY_USER_TAGS, tags);

    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),JSON_STRING.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Basically your tags string will get populated only after `shoEmployee()` finishes up and that will get called after `onPostExecute` of `GetJSON`.

Comment: i get the same bank toast . any other idea.?

Comment: i get the toast like this:: {"result":[]}

Comment: have you removed the other toast?

Comment: Yes.. i have removed

Answer (score 0):

Modify your showEmployee like this:

```
private void showEmployee() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONObject result = jsonObject.getJSONObject(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONArray jsonTags = result.getJSONArray(KEY_USER_TAGS);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonTags.length(); i++) {
            tags = tags + jsonTags.getString(i);

            HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(KEY_USER_TAGS, jsonTags.getString(i));

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and set your tags string to an empty string (else the first object will be null)

```
   public static String tags = "";
```

The code still has some logic flaws, your employees HashMap will only contain the last entry, because you are always creating a new HashMap.

Comment: i get this : org.json.JSONException: Value [] at result of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject