# Array from MySQL to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

I'm getting data from the following table succsesfully.
[table "pagides"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hReE.jpg)

My php file is:

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id'];

require_once('dbconnectdakos.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Pagides WHERE id='".$id."'";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result,array(
"Code"=>$res['Code'],
"Latitude"=>$res['Latitude'],
"Longitude"=>$res['Longitude'],
"Trigger"=>$res['Trigger']
)
);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

}
```

the method I use is, (where i=1, and every time I need a new row, I set i=i+1)

```
    private void getData() {
    id = Integer.toString(i);

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Παρακαλώ περιμένετε...", "Λήψη δεδομένων...", false, false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL + id;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response) {
    String Code = "";
    String Latitude = "";
    String Longitude = "";
    String Trigger = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject tripData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        Code = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_CODE);
        Latitude = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_LATITUDE);
        Longitude = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_LONGITUDE);
        Trigger = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_TRIGGER);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(Latitude);
        Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(Longitude);
        Double trigger = Double.parseDouble(Trigger);

        LatLng latLngto = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLngto) //setting position
                .draggable(false) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Προορισμός")); //Adding a title

        toLatitude = latitude;
        toLongitude = longitude;
        TriggerGet = trigger;

}
```

and the config.java class is:

```
public class Config {
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://...../getDatadakos.php?id=";
public static final String KEY_CODE = "Code";
public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
public static final String KEY_TRIGGER = "Trigger";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

That worked great for my first app, where I wanted one point at a time to be loaded. Now I need all points from "pagides" table to be fetched at once, where code='".$code."', and then use each ones data, every time the user clicks on the according marker.

What changes do I have to make, to the php file and the getData() method to get the whole array, and not one row at a time?

I tried something like this, [Get a array from MySQL to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699185/get-a-array-from-mysql-to-android), but the app crashes all the time.

I also tried looping the getData() method. It got all the points, showed them on the map, but I could only use the data from the last point fetched.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Why don't you use mysqli_fetch_assoc() instead? Then you don't need to add the column names in?